# Android Studio does not rebuild project when changing Application.mk file

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-ndk

I'm in an Android project in Android Studio 2.2 and when I update the Application.mk file in the project and hit the Run or Make Project buttons, Gradle doesn't seem to think anything has changed in the project and quickly succeeds (but gives me the previous build).

If it matters, I was changing the `APP_STL` line in React Native's [Application.mk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/jni/Application.mk#L10).

The quickest way I found to workaround this is to rebuild the project (slow) or modify the Android.mk file in the project and hit Run or Make Project (faster) but it would be nice to not have to workaround this. Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug in Android Studio?

Comment: Have you filed a bug?

Answer (score 1):

**Application.mk** is not tracked as dependency by Android Studio, but you can override APP_STL in your **build.gradle**, and this change will be tracked.

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    externalNativeBuild {
      ndkBuild {
        cppFlags "-std=c++11"
        arguments "APP_STL=gnustl_static
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
 }}}}
```